# Evaluar si el valor de un campo especifico es igual en todas las filas de un array a un valor especificado

Tags: php, array, algoritmos, aplicación-web

¿Cómo puedo saber si el valor de un campo en todas las "filas" del array es el mismo con uno que yo quiero especificar? 
Ejemplo:

```
if(El_valor_del_campo_en_todas_las_filas == 0){
     Instrucciones...
}
```

¿Hay alguna función que haga esto? Estaba pensando en algo como esto:

```
function evaluar_campo($array,$clave_asociativa){
   $variable_control = 1;
   for ($i=0; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
       if($array[$i][$clave_asociativa] !== 0){
           $variable_control = 0; 
       }
   }
   return $variable_control;
}
```

Esta es una función que en teoria debería de retornar 1 si, sí es el mismo valor en todos las filas en ese campo y si hay alguno diferente devuelve un 0

```
if(evaluar_campo($array,"SALARIO") == 1){
   SON IGUALES
}else{
   NO SON IGUALES
}
```

¿Existe alguna función de PHP que haga esto? Seguramente tiene un mejor performance (Si existe)
Pero sino ¿Creen que esta es la manera mas adecuada de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) o  [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) para buscar un valor en un array.

Comment: sería mejor para la respuesta y para el OP mejorar este aporte agregando ejemplos de uso y aplicación de ambas, lo cual haría que la respuesta suba de calidad

Comment: Gracias, lo que pasa es que no quiero que la busqueda se haga en todos los campos del array sino que solo en uno, porque los otros campos pueden tener valores iguales (Con mucha seguridad) y en este caso solo es relevante la información de un campo

Comment: Por eso es que en el ejemplo, le mando como segundo parametro a la función la clave asociativa o valor asociativo para que busque solo en ese campo.
Estoy haciendo unos filtros por campos